# Bazel Key Expired Error when sudo apt-get update Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, bazel, apt-get

I am getting the following error when I do

Command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Error:

```
Err:10 http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease
The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1527185977  KEYEXPIRED 1527185977  KEYEXPIRED 1527185977
Hit:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1527185977  KEYEXPIRED 1527185977  KEYEXPIRED 1527185977
W: Failed to fetch http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1527185977  KEYEXPIRED 1527185977  KEYEXPIRED 1527185977
```

How do I resolve it?

Comment: "KEYEXPIRED issues" : Probably get a new key https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-ubuntu.html#install-on-ubuntu ... `curl https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`

Comment: it doesn't resolve the issue. @KnudLarsen

Comment: OK, then you can disable the repo, https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu ... If you want the latest = `docker-ce_18.03.1~ce-0~ubuntu_amd64.deb `, it's here : https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/pool/stable/amd64/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$ curl https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
# Followed by
$ sudo apt-get update
```

(via https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5261#issuecomment-392044252)

Comment: Just a heads up: I first thought the script stalled but it is waiting for the sudo password.